# Retrieve Standard Picklist Value Sets using package.xml

Tags: managed-package, deployment, picklist, package.xml, financial-services-cloud

There are standard picklist fields like Premium Frequency on Insurance Policy object in Financial Services Cloud package.

We have added some new picklist values for this field.

However, we are not able to retrieve these values using package.xml. Also, tried appending the package name 'FinServ__' but it didn't work out. Below are the options tried for retrieving which didn't work:

```
   <types>
    <members>InsurancePolicyPremiumFrequency</members>
    <members>InsurancePolicy.PremiumFrequency</members>
    <members>FinServ__InsurancePolicyPremiumFrequency</members>
    <members>FinServ__InsurancePolicy.PremiumFrequency</members>
    <members>InsurancePolicyFinServ__PremiumFrequency</members>
    <members>FinServ__InsurancePolicyFinServ__PremiumFrequency</members>
    <name>StandardValueSet</name>
   </types>
```

How can we retrieve the new picklist values added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it finally. We need to use '**IPolicy**' instead of '**InsurancePolicy**' for Insurance Policy and '**IPC**' for Insurance Policy Coverage Standard Value Sets.

For the field **PremiumFrequency** on **InsurancePolicy** object, this works:

```
<types>
   <members>IPolicyPremiumFrequency</members>
   <name>StandardValueSet</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Are we able to use * to pull ALL the StandardValueSet?

Comment: No, * is not allowed for StandardValueSet.

Comment: How did you figure this?

Comment: By contacting the Salesforce Support team.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with financial service cloud package, but it looks like you're using the right type, but maybe not the correct name. You simply just need to pass the FieldAPIName for the picklist.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_object_reference.meta/financial_services_cloud_object_reference/sforce_api_objects_insurancepolicy.htm

```
<type>
    <member>PremiumFrequency</member>
    <name>StandardValueSet</name>
</type>
```

I believe you can also go about it the following way as well.

```
<types>
    <members>InsurancePolicy.PremiumFrequency</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Got the error `Entity of type 'StandardValueSet' named 'PremiumFrequency' cannot be found`. For the custom field `InsurancePolicy.PremiumFrequency`, I have the field but can't see any picklist values there. This is because it is a standard picklist field and we need to retrieve StandardValueSet in order to get the picklist values.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of any help, I don't have Financial Cloud so I'm unable to test anything out. This would be something that I would create a case for to figure out what "name" it expects as it's not listed in the documentation for standardvalueset names.